# Slickgrid - dataView.setGrouping is not a function

Tags: grouping, slickgrid, aggregation

I am trying to follow the code in the example:

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping

I am getting the error:

dataView.setGrouping is not a function

Am I missing a js include? Does anyone know where this function is defined?

Comment: Apparently I have the wrong version of slickgrid. 

I looked at the slick.dataview.js file on the site and seems my file is outdated, the setGrouping function is present there. 

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/90964ce5541bc2f381b6c60893f60029f24f907b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I have the wrong version of slickgrid.

I looked at the slick.dataview.js file on the site and seems my file is outdated, the setGrouping function is present there.

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/90964ce5541bc2f381b6c60893f60029f24f907b